# How to write integration test for complicated rails index (best practices)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

Let's say I have a page which lists articles. The code in the controller used to be

```
# articles#index
@articles = Article.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10, order: :title)
```

and my test was like

```
# spec/requests/article_pages_spec
Article.paginate(page: 1, per_page:10, order: :title).each do |a|
  a.should have_selector('h3', text: a.title)
end
```

Ok fine. Now my code changes a bunch. The index is like

```
@articles = Article.find(:all, conditions: complicated_status_conditions)
  .sort_by { |a| complicated_weighted_rating_stuff }
  .select { |a| complicated_filters }
  .paginate(...)
```

Or something. So what should my request spec now look like? I don't want to just copy and paste the application code into the test, but at the same time, the conditions and ordering are now fairly complex, so testing the existence and order of all the expected elements will definitely fail unless I emulate the index controller.

What's the best way to do this, avoid testing so specifically, copy in the application code? Refactor the query to some central place like a model and re-use it in the tests?

Comment: Why did the code change?  Was there a new requirement?  If so, the test should reflect that new requirement.

Comment: Yes, several complicated sorting and filtering requirements. For instance, sorting by weighted rating, and adding a time decay on the weighted ratings. Doing that heuristically in a test seems imprecise and won't produce the same results as the actual code, but replicating the same query in the test seems redundant...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# articles#index
@articles = Article.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10, order: :title)
```

The way we test this is *not* by writing `Article.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10, order: :title)` again in the spec. The spec must test the result of your program code, not copying over your program code itself!

Long story short - you must just call `articles#index` controller, and afterwards just check the `@articles` variable. i.e.

```
# We usually call this as a controller spec
# spec/controllers/articles_controller
# But feel free to put it anywhere you want
describe ArticlesController do
  it "should ..." do
    get :index

    # assigns[:articles] will give the @articles variable contents
    assigns[:articles].each do |a|
      response.should have_selector('h3', text: a.title)
    end
  end
end
```

This way, you directly test using the `@articles` variable itself, without having to do a second query (which both consumes unnecessary time, as well as results in copying over code).

If you want to test the actual query itself, then since your query is complicated, you should write a spec like the following:

```
it "should ..." do
  # Create 10 articles in the database
  # out of which only 5 are expected to match the expected output
  article1  = Article.create! ...
  ...
  article10 = Article.create! ...

  get :index

  # Test whether the articles are correctly filtered and ordered
  assigns[:articles].should == [article5, article3, article7, article1, article4]
```

Edit: Footnote
Edit 2: Added extra example for testing the actual query

Comment: So I infer from this that what you're testing there is the fact that the action spits out the results from the controller, NOT that the controller produces the right results? And therefore, the test(s) for the controller selecting the right results goes somewhere else?

Comment: yes @futuresandwich, the output of the controller is a different spec. The controller selecting the right results using the right query is a different spec, and the best way to test *that* would be to first save 10 articles in the database (out of which only 5 match all the conditions), invoke the controller, and then asserting that `assigns[:articles]` has the right 5 article IDs.

Comment: For future readers of this post - You people also can read [this article](http://everydayrails.com/2015/04/05/rspec-assigns-rails-testing.html).