# `Assigns` isn't working in my integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing

I'm trying to write a test following the suggestion on https://stackoverflow.com/a/17002140/4499505.

My simplified test:

```
test "test" do
  log_in_as(@user)
  get users_path
  assert_template 'users/index'
  assigns[:users].each do 
    assert_select 'a[href=?]', users_path(user)
  end
end
```

The error result:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

The controller method:

```
  def index
    @users_grid = initialize_grid(User.where(verified: true),
      per_page:        15,
      order:           'users.username',
      order_direction: 'desc')
  end
```

Apparantly `assigns[:users]` is empty even though there are users in the fixtures file. What am I doing wrong? I understand the `assigns[:users]` should assign the exact same users as shown on `users/index`, which is exactly what I want.

Comment: show your controller action......

Comment: Added to original post

Comment: You need to do `assigns[:users_grid]`

Comment: Thanks, this seems to give progress but it now gives an error related to the next line (the `assert_select` line): `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'user' `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your correct code is :

```
test "test" do
  log_in_as(@user)
  get users_path
  assert_template 'users/index'
  # in your controller you have the instance var as 
  # @users_gird, not @users.
  assigns[:users_grid].each do 
    assert_select 'a[href=?]', users_path(@user)
  end
end
```

[`assigns` is a hash](http://everydayrails.com/2015/04/05/rspec-assigns-rails-testing.html), accessible within *Rails* tests, containing all the **instance variables that would be available to a view at this point**. It’s also an accessor that allows you to look up an attribute with a symbol (since, historically, the assigns hash’s keys are all strings). In other words, `assigns(:contact)` is the same as `assigns["contact"]`.

Comment: Thanks, this produced the error `ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]`. In development, the page works correctly.

Comment: It had the same error message I'm afraid. `users_path` is an index that shouldn't take an id/parameter... The error message refers to the show method so it seems... The relevant route is: `users GET    /users(.:format)   users#index`

Comment: @Nick What is the line number from where error has been thrown ?

Comment: The `assert_select` line.

Comment: Ah, last time I copied it incorrectly from your example. I now have it working. It needs to be `userS_path(@user)` after all. Thanks!

Comment: How should `assigns` work when the variable in the controller method is not unique? That is: what if there were multiple controllers with the variable `users_grid`?

Answer (score 0):

Notice in the answer you've linked to that the symbol in `assigns[]` matches that of the instance variable from the controller action.

In your case you're assigning the instance variable `@users_grid` but attempting to iterate through `assigns[:users]`. You probably just want to change the latter to `assigns[:users_grid]`